# Number of times a constructor is called

Tags: c++, class, constructor, copy-constructor

Let's say that we have a Custom String class that looks as following

```
using namespace std;

class CustomStr {
public:
  const char* s;

  // converting constructor
  CustomStr(const char* s) : s (s) {
    cout << "Constructor called" << endl;
  }

  // Copy constructor    
  CustomStr(const CustomStr& cs) : s (cs.s) {
    cout << "Copy Constructor called" << endl;
  }
};
```

Let's consider the following code:

```
int main() {
  CustomStr cs("Some char pointer");
  CustomStr cs_copy = cs;
  return 0;
}
```

In the case above, we would expect converting constructor to be called first and copy constructor to be called after that for `CustomStr cs_copy = cs`, and we get the corresponding output as expected

```
$ ./a.out
Constructor called
Copy Constructor called
```

Now, consider the following code

```
int main() {
  CustomStr cs_copy = CustomStr("Some char pointer");
  return 0;
}
```

In this case as well, I thought 2 constructor calls should be made - converting constructor call for `CustomStr("Some char pointer")` and copy constructor call for `CustomStr cs_copy = CustomStr("Some char pointer")`. But, the output shows only converting constructor being called.

I was not able to explain how this was happening. I would expect it to be a low hanging fruit for compiler to optimize - but I wanted to understand under what cases this optimization kicks in.

Comment: Yes, this is a compiler optimization. The rules for when this and other kinds of optimizations are permissible have changed -- sometimes quite drastically -- in recent C++ revisions. In some cases a compiler is allowed to optimize away an copy construction or copy assignment even if it has side effects. In some cases it's even ***required***. One does not have to worry about this -- stick to the rules. Do not introduce fragile dependencies on copy constructors or copy assignments taking place, in specific situations, and let the compiler worry about generating correct code.

Comment: Note "default constructor" is a technical term which does not describe your first constructor. A "default constructor" in the usual sense is one that can be used with zero arguments.  So either `CustomStr();` or `CustomStr(const char* s = nullptr);` would be a default constructor.

Comment: @aschepler - Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the question accordingly

Answer (score 3):

Quote from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization):

> if the initializer is a prvalue expression whose type is the same class as T (ignoring cv-qualification), the initializer expression itself, rather than a temporary materialized from it, is used to initialize the destination object

`CustomStr("Some char pointer")` is a prvalue of the same type as `cs_copy`. Therefore there is no temporary and no copy. `cs_copy` is simply directly initialised from that expression.

Prior to C++17, there used to be a temporary as far as the abstract machine was concerned, but the standard doesn't require the copy constructor to be called, and therefore the same behaviour as C++17 has was allowed as an optimisation. More details at cppreference: [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision).

Comment: "*Default constructors do not take arguments*" - more accurately, they can take arguments, as long as they have default values.  A default constructor is CALLED with no argument values specified.  For example: `CustomStr(const char* s = NULL)` is a valid default constructor AND a converting constructor.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I corrected the sentence to not be incorrect.

Comment: @eerorika - I have edited the question to remove 'default constructor' and use 'converting constructor'

Comment: @ShauryaKumar I removed the obsolete post scriptum.

Answer (score 2):

Since C++17,  `T x = T(A);` is defined to mean exactly the same as: `T x(A);`. (where `A` is any, possibly empty, list of expressions, and there's no MVP).

Prior to C++17 the compiler was allowed to choose whether to process the code as `T x(A);`, or whether to construct a temporary and then copy/move construct `x` from the temporary.